# Using Parameters as Identifiers?

Tags: java, math, coordinates, equation, points

This may seem like a stupid question but I am new to Java. I am trying to find the distance of two points.  *Method Summary: Compute the distance between this Point and another Point*  When I try to compile I am getting the error: CANNOT FIND SYMBOL (in my double dx and double dy).  If anyone could help with this it would be appreciated. Below is my code.

```
public class CartPoint implements Point{

  private Double x;
  private Double y;

  public CartPoint (double x, double y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

  }
  public double x(){
    return x;
  }

  public double y(){
    return y;
  }

  public double distanceFrom(Point other){
    double dx = (other.x - this.x);
    double dy = (other.y - this.y);
    return Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
  }
```

//INTERFACE

```
public interface Point{
    double x();
    double y();
}
```

Comment: I don't get that error when I drop your code into eclipse, though I *do* get errors that `other.x` and `other.y` cannot be resolved (which makes sense since `other` is a `Point` and not a `CartPoint`).

Comment: So can I convert other to a CartPoint and then use it?

Comment: Sure, see Mureinik's answer.

Comment: Well do you want to be able to compute the distance between a `CartPoint` and a *different* `Point` implementation? (You may well find that doesn't make sense...)

Comment: Should be double dx = (other.x() - this.x()).  You need to call the method on the Point interface.  You can't access the private members directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x` and `y` are members of the `CartPoint` class, not the `Point` class, so you should use that as a parameter class:

```
public double distanceFrom(CartPoint other) {
```

Alternatively, you could add `getX()` and `getY()` methods the `Point` interface and use them:

```
public double distanceFrom(Point other){
    double dx = (other.getX() - getX());
    double dy = (other.getY() - getY());
    return Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
}
```

EDIT:
Now that you've edited the question and shown you have `x()` and `y()` methods in the interface, that's what you should use:

```
public double distanceFrom(Point other){
    double dx = (other.x() - x());
    double dy = (other.y() - y());
    return Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
}
```

Comment: Given that `Point` is an interface, the fields can't be specified there. Perhaps there are `getX` and `getY` methods though?

Comment: Point is an interface, should I define x & y in that?

Comment: @J.Daniels as John suggested - if that's the way you're going, you should have getters in the interface. See my edited answer.

Comment: @Mureinik  thank you for your help, I believe I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work AND be less prone to roundoff errors:

```
public double distanceFrom(Point other){
    double distance = 0.0;
    double dx = Math.abs(other.x() - this.x());
    double dy = Math.abs(other.y() - this.y());
    if (dx > dy) {
        double ratio = dy/dx;
        distance = dx*Math.sqrt(1.0+ratio*ratio);
    } else {
        double ratio = dx/dy;
        distance = dy*Math.sqrt(1.+ratio*ratio);
    }
    return distance;
}
```

Be aware that this distance formula is only appropriate for 2D Cartesian coordinate systems.  The distance on a spherical coordinate system is very different.